# How can I change the global repromesh texture in Mash?

Tags: maya

I have mash network coming from 9 planes with 9 shading group & textures. I woulk like to switch texture/shading group during the animation (with planar projection). Is there a way to add a node between the repromesh and the differents shading group, in order to control this effect easily ? (I would like also to comes back to the 9 original shading groups, and fade between them)

[image: My original mash network]
[image: its node system]
This is what I would like to achieve easily
[image: What I could like to get]
[image: the node scema associated]
With the possibility to reverse to the original node structure, and even to get a fade with another planar projection (with set3 in the example below)

[image: possibility to fade]

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just add blendcolor nodes to your existing materials, combining two different sets of looks ,  and then cross-fade them with keyed blend attribute? Switching the materials changes the shape of the evaluation graph, where changing an attribute within the blends does not.

Comment: I don"t know. The fact is I would like to combine a global texture (with planar projection) for the repromesh with all the "inherited" texture I got when I have created the mash network. How can the blendcolor node do that ?

Comment: Does one texture exist in world space and the other in UV space? Or do both of them move with the individual pieces?

Comment: Yes. One texture exists in world space (planar projection / camera) and the others one are attached to each plane

Comment: Maybe you can just add a second UV channel to do the second image channel, then you just have a blend between two simple shaders